# Variables in .kv and in python code do not sync up

Tags: python, kivy, desktop-application, kivy-language

When I try to access TextInput that has id total_area from my python code, I get this error: AttributeError: 'kivy.properties.ObjectProperty' object has no attribute 'text'. I used debugger to see whats wrong and it seems to me that variables in python code are not getting linked to those in kv file. Help
Python code:

```
class RootWidget(Widget):

    Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', '0')
    Config.set('graphics', 'height', '720')
    Config.set('graphics', 'width', '480')

    koatuu_obl_cent = ObjectProperty()
    koatuu_city = ObjectProperty()
    kitchen_area = ObjectProperty()
    qt_room = ObjectProperty()
    floor = ObjectProperty()
    qt_floor = ObjectProperty()
    total_area = ObjectProperty()
    living_area = ObjectProperty()
    year_building = ObjectProperty()

    @classmethod
    def button_OnPress(self):
        print(self.total_area.text)


class DeepEval(App):

    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    DeepEval().run()
```

.kv:

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<MyPopup@Popup>:
    auto_dismiss: False

    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 400

<RootWidget>

    koatuu_obl_cent: koatuu_obl_cent
    koatuu_city: koatuu_city
    kitchen_area: kitchen_area
    qt_room: qt_room
    floor: floor
    qt_floor: qt_floor
    total_area: total_area
    living_area: living_area
    year_building: year_building

    Image:
        source: 'imgs/background.jpg'
        size: self.texture_size

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'center'
        size: root.width, root.height

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            height: 350
            width: 225
            size_hint_x: None
            size_hint_y: None
            spacing: 22.5

            TextInput:
                id: total_area
                multiline: False
                hint_text: "Param12"
                halign: 'center'
                foreground_color: .5, .5, .5, .75
                height: 33
                width: 225
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None

            TextInput:
                id: kitchen_area
                multiline: False
                hint_text: "Param1"
                halign: 'center'
                foreground_color: .5, .5, .5, .75
                height: 33
                width: 225
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None

            TextInput:
                id: living_area
                multiline: False
                hint_text: "Param1"
                halign: 'center'
                foreground_color: .5, .5, .5, .75
                height: 33
                width: 225
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None

            TextInput:
                id: qt_room
                multiline: False
                hint_text: "Param1"
                halign: 'center'
                foreground_color: .5, .5, .5, .75
                height: 33
                width: 225
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None

            TextInput:
                id: floor
                multiline: False
                hint_text: "Param1"
                halign: 'center'
                foreground_color: .5, .5, .5, .75
                height: 33
                width: 225
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None

            TextInput:
                id: qt_floor
                multiline: False
                hint_text: "Param1"
                halign: 'center'
                foreground_color: .5, .5, .5, .75
                height: 33
                width: 225
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None

            TextInput:
                id: year_building
                multiline: False
                hint_text: "Param1"
                halign: 'center'
                foreground_color: .5, .5, .5, .75
                height: 33
                width: 225
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None

            Button:
                id: koatuu_obl_cent
                text: 'Open popup'
                on_release: Factory.MyPopup().open()
                height: 33
                width: 225
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None

            Button:
                id: koatuu_city
                text: 'Open popup'
                on_release: Factory.MyPopup().open()
                height: 33
                width: 225
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None

        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: "center"
            anchor_y: "bottom"
            padding: 0,0,0,25

            Button:
                text: "Calculate"
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 50
                width: 135
                on_press: root.button_OnPress()

        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: "right"
            anchor_y: "bottom"

            Button:
                text: "cam"
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 45
                width: 45
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@classmethod
def button_OnPress(self):
    print(self.total_area.text)
```

Your wrote @classmethod so you got a class method, whose first argument is not an instance of the class (usually called `self`) but rather the class itself (usually called `cls`).

Your `self.total_area` is therefore equivalently `RootWidget.total_area` which is, as the error says, an ObjectProperty.

You need to access the total_area as an attribute of an instance of your class. In this case, remove the `@classmethod`.

Comment: That did it. Thanks a lot!